# How to solve this error: associated type `BlockNumber` not found for `T`?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, error, babe, orml-xtokens

I have substrate node template with babe and i want to integrate `orml-currencies`.

I'm using this in cargo.toml:

> orml-currencies = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

Then I'm getting this error:

```
--> /Users/deepak/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d3634ee624a28945/6819d3f/tokens/src/lib.rs:433:18
      |
  433 |     impl<T: Config> GenesisBuild<T> for GenesisConfig<T> {
      |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: consider importing this trait
      |
  179 +     use frame_support::traits::GenesisBuild;
      |

  error[E0220]: associated type `BlockNumber` not found for `T`
      --> /Users/deepak/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d3634ee624a28945/6819d3f/tokens/src/lib.rs:1277:19
       |
  1277 |     type Moment = T::BlockNumber;
       |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ there is a similarly named associated type `BlockNumber` in the trait `BlockNumberProvider`

  error[E0220]: associated type `BlockNumber` not found for `T`
      --> /Users/deepak/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d3634ee624a28945/6819d3f/tokens/src/lib.rs:2403:19
       |
  2403 |     type Moment = T::BlockNumber;
       |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ there is a similarly named associated type `BlockNumber` in the trait `BlockNumberProvider`
```

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Polkadot Release Analysis `v1.0.0`](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/polkadot-release-analysis-v1-0-0/3585/4#genesisbuildti-deprecated-buildgenesisconfig-added-2), `GenesisBuild` has been has been deprecated in favor of `BuildGenesisConfig`. Here is an example of how to use:

```rust
#[pallet::genesis_config]
#[derive(frame_support::DefaultNoBound)]
pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> {
     _config: sp_std::marker::PhantomData<(T,I)>,
    _myfield: u32,
}
    
#[pallet::genesis_build]
impl<T: Config<I>, I: 'static> BuildGenesisConfig for GenesisConfig<T, I> {
    fn build(&self) {}
}
```

I believe there was a change with `BlockNumber` as well:

- https://forum.polkadot.network/t/polkadot-release-analysis-v1-0-0/3585/3#moves-block-to-frame_system-instead-of-construct_runtime-and-removes-header-and-blocknumber-1

I believe you can use `BlockNumberFor<T>` instead of `BlockNumber`.

You can reference the Cumulus PR for examples:

- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/2790/files

Comment: Thank you for the support. But I'm not able to understand where I need to implement this genesisConfig or BlockNumberFor? I just want to integrate the orml pallets in our project and when I add this in cargo.toml, I'm getting error. Can you please elaborate the solution more?

Comment: The best help I can give you is to check out the associated Cumulus PRs for each of these PRs. They show concrete examples of what changes you would need to make in your node.